# How can I prevent the latest version of the file from being overwritten by a previous version in SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a file called "File1.txt"  which resides in the following folder

D:\Dev\File1(v1).txt

(v1) --> Denotes version number

When the file is ready for production we have a release process by which the file is moved to Prod in v weeks time. Lets assume the production folder is

D:\Prod\File1(v1).txt

If we make any further changes to File1.txt in Dev then we release this into production (in 2 weeks time)

So now we the Dev and Prod folder status as follows
DEV : D:\Dev\File1(v2).txt --> Today

PROD : D:\Prod\File1(v2).txt --> 2 weeks time

Sometimes we need to make emergency releases into production so we may bypass the normal 2 week release process and transfer the file into production immediately.

this means the Dev and Prod folder status as follows
DEV : D:\Dev\File1(v3).txt --> Today

PROD : D:\Prod\File1(v3).txt --> Today

However in 2 weeks time as part of the normal release process File(2).txt will override the emergency release File1(v3).txt

this means the Dev and Prod folder status as follows
IN 2 WEEKS FROM NOW
===================
DEV : D:\Dev\File1(v3).txt

PROD : D:\Prod\File1(v2).txt

How can I prevent the latest version of the file from being overwritten by a previous version?

Comment: What process (a svn command?) copies the file in two weeks time?

Comment: Why would the v2 and v3 versions of the file be different? If they're different, this means that the tests done during the two-weeks release process don't serve any purpose, since they would test a version of the application that doesn't go into production (since it tests the v2 version, but you want to keep the v3 version). So you should just cancel the two-weeks release, and redo a complete release with the v3 version.

Comment: send this information to the release process - or tell us what you use during this release process.

Comment: @JB Nizet: have you ever headrd of hot fix? If you cancel release each time you have a new hot fix you would not release at all...

Comment: Except the hot fix should be replaced by the full tested release. The OP wants to keep its hotfix despite having a tested full release available. If you accept hotfixes, then also accept to hotfix a release being under test, and do the release with the hotfix included. BTW, I never release a single file. I always release a complete, tagged release (whether it has been fully tested or not).

Comment: Additionally, if you have so many hotfixes to do, I would say that your development and testing methodology is broken.

Comment: @DougCurrie - i do not know what svn command is used to copy file in 2 weeks time. But I can find out if it helps

Comment: @JBNizet - The file change may be a small part of the release process. We may want all other components that need to go through the release process. Sometimes we may not be able to redo a release process for the sake of one file

Comment: Then include the v3 file into the release during the 2-weeks release process, or redo the v3 hotfix after the release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formulate your process in version control terms: You have essentially three active branches in your project. They are development (probably trunk), release candidate and production. During your normal workflow, you branch the release candidate off the development branch, let it simmer for two weeks and then make it the production branch two weeks later.

If you have a hotfix, it is applied to both production and development. In addition, you should apply it to any release candidate branch.
Since your error essentially boils down to the production branch file (v2) overwriting the hotfixed file (v3), this just means that you have not applied the hotfix to your release candidate. You have two ways to remedy this:

1. Make it crystal clear to all developers that a hotfix is applied to all three branches.
2. Merge the release candidate branch into production instead of replacing production. (Not sure this will work out technically in all scenarios.)